# In react-native App when creating pod file the target is empty

Tags: ios, cocoapods

In my react-native app I want to integrate cocoapod,after 
sudo gem install cocoapods. When I create the pod file is using pod init command ,then the pod file is missing the target .

Below is the pod file code.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target '    ' do
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!

# Pods for  

end
```

Due to this when installing pod framework ,its not working.